# Powershell doesn't output contenttype

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, document-library, content-type

I have the following script which should output the name of the content type for each list item however it is not, where am I going wrong? The output for both Id and Name is just a blank line, clearly loops through each item yet doesn't find the content type field

```
$qCommand = @"
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
    <Query>
        <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">5000</RowLimit>
</View>
"@
## Page Position
$position = $null

## All Items
$allItems = @()
Do
{
    $camlQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $position
    $camlQuery.ViewXml = $qCommand

    ## Executing the query
    $currentCollection = $list.GetItems($camlQuery)
    $ctx.Load($currentCollection)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    ## Getting the position of the previous page
    $position = $currentCollection.ListItemCollectionPosition

    # Adding current collection to the allItems collection
    $allItems += $currentCollection
}
# the position of the last page will be Null
Until($position -eq $null) 

$results = ""
foreach($item in $allItems)
{ 
    $CT = $item.ContentType
    write-host $item.ContentType.Id
    write-host $item.ContentType.Name
    if($CT -eq "Land")
    {
        $item["FileLeafRef"] | Out-File "C:\temp\test.csv" -append
    }
}
```

Comment: can you do $ct.count?

Comment: Changed $item.ContentType.Id for $CT.count and it outputs 1 everytime

Comment: it seems adding ctx.load($ct) $ctx.ExecuteQuery() has got it working

Comment: @charlie - please close question or provide Your own answer with final script.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86592/discussion-on-question-by-charlie-powershell-doesnt-output-contenttype).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
$CT = $item.ContentType
```

try using

```
$CT = $item["ContentType"]
```